# C - Arrays, Sorting, and Modifying

Tags: c, arrays, io, qsort

Been working on a task that has been the subject of a whole variety of other question on SO!
I've gotten to the stage where again, I am trying to append a number to an array, though this time, the code is more complex in the way info is passed around in parameters.

EDIT: Code is also below

Sorry about this, but please fine the code: http://pastebin.com/8SUjRyZQ

There is a little too much to place on a forum post.

The issue is, it isn't appending the number, but just garbage, although this time, I really can't see why as I have taken into account all the suggestions from my previous questions on this topic.

It should append the number, int val, to the array, within the `void AppendInt` function, thought its just appending garbage.

Well, in Notepad++, it prints the Word - PasswordBOH - BOH being some random garbage, its like an image, BOH in white text with a black background.

Anyone help is appreciated!

PS> If needed, I can post the code here, but it's a substantial chunk.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXLINES 5000 /* max no. lines to be stored */
#define MAXLEN 1000 /* max length of single line */

char *lineptr[MAXLINES];

void capitalise(char *line);
void decision(int i, char *line, int val);
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void qksort(char *v[], int left, int right);
void swap(char *v[], int i, int j);
void AppendInt(char *line, int val, int length);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int nlines = 0, j, k, i = 0;
char line[MAXLEN];
FILE *fpIn;

printf("WLO v1.0 Alpha Release - Coded in C - Big Shout to StackOverFlow!\n");
printf("1.QuickSort List.\n");
printf("2.QuickSort - Capitalise Word[0]\n");
printf("3.QuickSort - Capitalise Word[0] - Append X\n");
scanf("%d", &k);

if(k == 3) {
    printf("Enter the value you wish to append (a single Integer): ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
}

fpIn = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
while((fgets(line, 65, fpIn)) != NULL) {
    j = strlen(line);
    if (j > 0 && (line[j-1] == '\n')) {
        line[j-1] = '\0';
    }
    if (j > 8) {
        if(k != 1)
            decision(k, line, i);
        lineptr[nlines++] = strdup(line);
    }
}
qksort(lineptr, 0, nlines - 1);
writelines(lineptr, nlines);
return 0;    
}

void decision(int i, char *line, int val) {
 if(i == 2)
    capitalise(line);
 else if(i == 3)
     AppendInt(line, val, strlen(line));
}

void capitalise(char *line) {
 line[0] = toupper((line[0]));
}

void AppendInt(char *line, int val, int length){
 capitalise(line);
 line[length] = val;
 line[length + 1] = '\0';    
}

void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines) {
FILE *fpOut;
int i;
fpOut = fopen("tmp.out", "wb");
for(i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
    fprintf(fpOut, "%s\n", lineptr[i]);   
}

void qksort(char *v[], int left, int right) {     
int i, last;
void swap(char *v[], int i, int j);
if (left >= right) 
        return; 
swap(v, left, (left + right)/2);
last = left;
for (i = left+1; i <= right; i++)
        if (strcmp(v[i], v[left]) < 0)
               swap(v, ++last, i);
        swap(v, left, last);
        qksort(v, left, last-1);
        qksort(v, last+1, right);
}

void swap(char *v[], int i, int j) {
 char *temp;  
 temp = v[i];
 v[i] = v[j];
 v[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: post resume pseudo code at least. or algorithm...

Comment: what do you mean by garbage ? can you post the content of the first lines of the file and the first printed lines ?

Comment: Well, in Notepad++, it prints the Word - PasswordBOH   - BOH being some random garbage, its like an image, BOH in white text with a black background.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `qsort` from `stdlib.h`?

Comment: in "tmp.out" there is only  PasswordBOH written ? but in original file there is Password ?

Comment: Yes, though there are more then 1 word, but they are all output in that way .

Comment: and yes, using the qsort algorithm from K and R, I wanted to work through that.

Comment: note that you leak memory by using `strdup` without releasing it (using `free`).

Comment: via free(strdup(line)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
void AppendInt(char *line, int val, int length) {
    capitalise(line);
    sprintf(line+length, "%d", val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you consider that val is not a char, so it is not printable...

to solve that :   `sprintf(&line[length],"%d",val);`

you have to be sure that you allocate enough memory for line to contain val.